# Incluir una dll como referencia y llamar objetos de su clase

Tags: c#

Quiero llamar la funcion principal de la siguiente clase:

```
class Program
{
    static Pool _pool = null;
    static Work _work = null;
    static uint _nonce = 0;
    static long _maxAgeTicks = 20000 * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
    static uint _batchSize = 100000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                _pool = SelectPool();
                _work = GetWork();
                while (true)
                {
                    if (_work == null || _work.Age > _maxAgeTicks)
                        _work = GetWork();

                    if (_work.FindShare(ref _nonce, _batchSize))
                    {
                        SendShare(_work.Current);
                        _work = null;
                    }
                    else
                        PrintCurrentState();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("ERROR: ");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Hit 'Enter' to try again...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    private static void ClearConsole()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("*****************************");
        Console.WriteLine("*** Minimal Bitcoin Miner ***");
        Console.WriteLine("*****************************");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static Pool SelectPool()
    {
        ClearConsole();
        Print("Chose a Mining Pool 'user:password@url:port' or leave empty to skip.");
        Console.Write("Select Pool: ");
        string login = ReadLineDefault("lithander_2:foo@btcguild.com:8332");
        return new Pool(login);
    }

    private static Work GetWork()
    {
        ClearConsole();
        Print("Requesting Work from Pool...");
        Print("Server URL: " + _pool.Url.ToString());
        Print("User: " + _pool.User);
        Print("Password: " + _pool.Password);
        return _pool.GetWork();
    }

    private static void SendShare(byte[] share)
    {
        ClearConsole();
        Print("*** Found Valid Share ***");
        Print("Share: " + Utils.ToString(_work.Current));
        Print("Nonce: " + Utils.ToString(_nonce));
        Print("Hash: " + Utils.ToString(_work.Hash));
        Print("Sending Share to Pool...");
        if (_pool.SendShare(share))
            Print("Server accepted the Share!");
        else
            Print("Server declined the Share!");

        Console.Write("Hit 'Enter' to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static DateTime _lastPrint = DateTime.Now;
    private static void PrintCurrentState()
    {
        ClearConsole();
        Print("Data: " + Utils.ToString(_work.Data));
        string current = Utils.ToString(_nonce);
        string max = Utils.ToString(uint.MaxValue);
        double progress = ((double)_nonce / uint.MaxValue) * 100;
        Print("Nonce: " + current + "/" + max + " " + progress.ToString("F2") + "%");
        Print("Hash: " + Utils.ToString(_work.Hash));
        TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - _lastPrint;
        Print("Speed: " + (int)(((_batchSize) / 1000) / span.TotalSeconds) + "Kh/s"); 
        _lastPrint = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private static void Print(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static string ReadLineDefault(string defaultValue)
    {
        //Allow Console.ReadLine with a default value
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        if (userInput == "")
            return defaultValue;
        else
            return userInput;
    }
}
```

Creo una nueva aplicacion de consola ,agrego la dll, pongo la clase y la llamada al método de la clase:

```
using Example;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Prueba
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            metodo();
        }

        private static void metodo()
        {
            Program.Main(); // aqui no puedo llamarlo
        }


    }
}
```

Cuando llamo main me da los siguientes errores:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0122  'Program' is inaccessible due to its protection
>   level ConsoleApplication1 c:\users\moh\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Prueba.cs   18  Active
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0103  The name 'args' does not exist in the current
>   context   ConsoleApplication1 c:\users\moh\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Prueba.cs   18  Active

Cual sería el método correcto de llamar a mi funcion main de mi .dll que he agregado como referencia y usa un nombre de espacios diferente¿?¿

Solucionado:
private static string[] args;

Sino se define el array como q no. total q soy retrasao por eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin analizar mucho el código, no es  `Prueba.Main();` es `Program.Main();`, y deberías pasarle algún *array* de *string* como parámetro (aunque sea uno vacío), ya que este es obligatorio en *Main*.

Comment: un ejemplo de como pasarle algun array de string como parametro?

Comment: string[] arr = new string[] {};

Comment: si soy retrasado esto lo confirma hasta el visual studio te lo resuelve solo

Comment: me votaria a mi mismo negativo pero no puedo

Comment: No hay problema, todos fuimos primerizos alguna vez ;-).

Comment: @OmarAlami si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la misma (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se benefician).

Answer (score 1):

Primero, creo que hiciste otra pregunta sobre este tema y se te dijo que para generar una dll debes crear un proyecto de tipo "Biblioteca de clases". Supongo que no lo has hecho, ya que una biblioteca de clases no tiene metodo "main"

Por otro lado, la clase a la que quieras llamar debe estar definida como public.